# eclipse RCP4 Add Toolbar to Parts

Tags: eclipse, e4

How to model a toolbar ONCE and render it in some Parts/Views (not in the default place which is the window!)? Using the model level (and maybe Addons?)

I have currently

1. Eclipse 2022.03-4.23
2. Application.e4xmi with that Toolbar but
3. Gets added dynamically using an Addon that listens to "PART_ADDED" event topic which
4. Leads to a NPE due to other event topic "UIEvents.Part.TOPIC_TOOLBAR" within a framework method in a class called LazyStackRenderer

So the guy before me had written an Addon to dynamically add the Toolbar to the parts. Maybe to make the buttons save/print per part or because the main layout has two stacks and only the parts stack is relevant.

Appreciate any help! I searched a lot but no success!

Comment: Can you clarify your question please, it is not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to add an `MToolBar` to an `MPart` dynamically? An NPE in LazyStackRenderer suggests the current code is doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes the current way is like what you said. Dynamically, an Addon listens to the the model. Once a Part is added, it makes  `addedPart.setToolbar(makeCopyOfMainToolBarOutOfModel())`  but this triggers another event in that LazyStackRenderer where the parent of the part is needed but is yet null. I did attach a parent to the part but ruins more than it helps. So I might just create that ToolBar directly in the PartDiscriptor

Answer (score 0):

I solved it so far. The dynamically created MParts were not added as children to the container (in my case the PartStack) in the first place and also had to comment the adding of placeholder objects that carry the same information of the parts. This dynamic step was done as a reaction to the topic `@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE)` in some written Addon.

I am not a 100% sure that discarding the placeholders is safe but still this is the best trail I have ever reached.

I hope this would help others!

Thank you @greg-449